# Why do we use asymmetric key cryptography to then just generate a symmetric key to use?

Tags: encryption, public-key

I'm learning about public key cryptography (asymmetric key cryptography), but from what I've gathered, we basically use public key crypto to just move directly onto private key cryptography (symmetric key cryptography).

Why not just always use asymmetric? (Note: I'm a software developer but not a cryptography expert. I'm just learning and find it fascinating. Thank you)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is asymmetric cryptography bad for huge data?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/why-is-asymmetric-cryptography-bad-for-huge-data) also [Why is hybrid encryption more effective than other encryption scheme?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31234/18298)

Comment: Asymmetric encryption is slow, so it's common to use asymmetric encryption to pass a symmetric encryption key to the other party and use something fast like AES to transfer data securely.

Comment: Asymmetric algorithms require longer keys (but this problem is partially eliminated by ECC), they operate slower than symmetric ones, they potentially produce bigger ciphertexts (if we talk about ciphers)

Comment: I don't like the term "private key cryptography" myself. If you'd use symmetric cryptography and you have more then one party, then the key cannot be kept private (to one party), but it does need to remain secret. So "secret key cryptography" seems more appropriate.